# How to set up a windows based front-end developer for contributing to a django based application

Tags: python, windows, django, web, collaboration

I am working on a project where I am quite comfortable running linux, virtualenv, pip, manage.py runserver, git and so on for back-end development.  I work with a front-end developer who needs to collaborate remotely, currently via a Dropbox synced copy of the codebase (also in a git branch) on Windows.  A development server on my side lets the developer see their changes semi-live.

Although this has served us fairly well so far, has anyone come across a similar working arrangement with a better setup for collaboration?

I'm mindful that the source control learning curve and environmental management overhead is potentially significant and somewhat unnecessary for front-end work (as long as I commit from time to time).  I'm considering a VM based setup such as BitNami's DjangoStack so that the front-end dev has their own server setup, but I thought I'd ask about other experiences.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) not only for quick development setups (which it excels at), but also for sharing VM configurations as you can publish your own vagrant file which your designer uses.

It relies on [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org/) <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle's open source hypervisor and is available for free on all major platforms.

Comment: I concur. Unless you're deploying to Windows as well, developing in an actual Windows development environment is going to do nothing but cause problems. You can set up shared folders between the Windows host and Linux guest, and your developer can use whatever tools he's most comfortable with in Windows to develop and simply run the code in the VM. Far easier. Set the VM's network adapter to bridged (gets its own IP) and then call runserver via: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. Your developer will then be able to preview the site in his Windows browsers (including IE).

Answer (score 0):

I have been in a very similar situation before Rog, where the backend was a Ruby on Rails setup running on *nix, and the frontend guy needed windows. We initially set up a Windows-Apache-MySql+git+RoR (using Cygwin and other tools) but eventually installing our app libraries and gems became a pain on the windows setup (anytime we would introduce a new gem (or app in django terms) the setup would break on windows). In the end we finally made the front-end guy work on *nix setup.

[andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) is extremely useful in these situations, it lets your run a seamless install of linux withing a windows 2000 setup, so the front end guy can still use windows tool. It is not like a dual boot, but here both the OS are running at the same time. Have a look into it.